# Accessing different parent controller from nested states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a state and a nested state as defined in `app.js`:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor'); 
    $stateProvider.state("feed", { //parent state
        url: "/feed",
        controller: "FeedCtrl as feed",
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/feed.html"
    })
    .state("feed.post", { //nested state
        url: "/post/:id",
        controller: "PostCtrl",
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/post.html"
    })
}
```

The controllers are different for both the states.

Also, the nested state's template isn't nested in the parent state's template. Both the templates `feed.html` and `post.html` are completely independent and separate.

Is nested state as defined in app.js sufficient to enforce parent-child relationship between the controllers or do the controllers and templates also need to be nested?

If yes, then how can I access the parent controller's scope from the child controller?

Answer (score 0):

Nested states as defined in app.js are required but not sufficient to enforce parent-child relationship.

Controller templates also need to be nested.

States can be nested using any of the four options below

*Using 'dot notation'. For example .state('contacts.list', {}).

*Use the ui-router.stateHelper to build states from a nested state tree.

*Using the parent property with the parent name as string. For example: parent: 'contacts'

*Using the parent property with the parent object. For example parent: contacts (where 'contacts' is a stateObject)

You can seek more details in doc [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

You can register states in any order and across modules. You can register children before the parent state exists. It will queue them up and once the parent state is registered then the child will be registered.

Parent state must exist and no two states can have the same name.

Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view.

Please ref [doc link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) for more details.